# populating sqlite3 db with links in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to populate a database with a single column with a list of strings (links). I scraped the list and I must modify every single link before sending it to the database. This is the code:

```
for event in events:
    link_url = "https://www.website.com"+event+"#all"
    c.execute("INSERT INTO table (links) VALUES(?)", link_url)
```

I can get it working if I modify the variables and send a tuple, like this:

```
for event in events:
    link_url = "https://www.website.com"+event+"#all"
    link = (link_url,)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO seriea (links) VALUES(?)", link_url)
```

but I don't want to use this solution since I want to get a list of strings back out later:

```
c = connection.execute('select links from table')
list_of_urls = c.fetchall()
```

But this gives me a list of tuples.

This is the error I have: ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 80 supplied.

I think that's because the string characters are counted (actually more but I noticed that the number before "supplied" changes with the link fed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use this solution since I want to get a list of strings back out later:
>
> ```
> c = connection.execute('select links from table')
> list_of_urls = c.fetchall()
> ```
>
> But this gives me a list of tuples.

The list of tuples you're getting when you do a select have nothing to do with the way you insert data. Remember, tables have two dimensions:

| id | links | something | else |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "foo" | "bar" | "baz" |
| 2 | "quux" | "herp" | "derp" |

When you do a select you get a list that corresponds to the rows here. But each row has multiple fields: `id`, `links`, `something`, and `else`. Each tuple in the list contains the values for each of the fields in the table.

If you just want the URLs as a list of strings you can use a list comprehension or similar:

```
c = connection.execute('select links from table')
list_of_rows = c.fetchall()
list_of_strings = [row[0] for row in list_of_rows]
#                      ^ index of first element in
#                  ^^^ the tuple of values for each row
```

Note that you do have to provide a tuple or other sequence when you insert the data:

> For the qmark style, `parameters` must be a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence). For the named style, it can be either a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) or [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) instance. The length of the [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) must match the number of placeholders, or a [`ProgrammingError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.ProgrammingError) is raised. If a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is given, it must contain keys for all named parameters.

You might be thinking of the tuple part of it the wrong way. You don't need to pass in a tuple of URLs, you need to pass in a tuple of *parameters*. You're not saying "the links column should contain this tuple" but rather "this tuple contains enough values to fill in the placeholders in this query".

I'd rewrite that like so:

```py
for event in events:
    link_url = "https://www.website.com"+event+"#all"
    c.execute("INSERT INTO seriea (links) VALUES(?)", (link_url,))
```

This is so you can have multiple parameters, e.g.

```py
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO seriea (links, some, other) VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
    (link_url, foo, bar),
)
```

> The current statement uses 1, and there are 80 supplied.
>
> I think that's because the string characters are counted

Yes, that's most likely what's happening. `c.execute()` expects to receive a sequence, and strings are a sequence of characters.